# 2d pose estimation in navigation with amcl

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rviz, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I launch these files:

```
$ roscore
$ roslaunch frontier_exploration robot.launch
$ roslaunch modeling display.launch model:="modeling/urdf/myrobot.urdf"
$ roslaunch frontier_exploration move_base_staticmap.launch
$ roslaunch frontier_exploration global_map.launch
```

in robot.launch I have the commands to start the lidar and tf transformations (scanmatcher -> base_link -> neato_laser);
in move_base_staticmap.launch I have this:

```
<launch>
<!-- Run the map server -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find robot_setup_tf)/mymaps/map.yaml" output="screen"/>
<include file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/amcl_diff.launch">
</include>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>

</launch>
```

Is it normal that I have to give the 2d pose estimate in rviz and it is not automatically done by amcl?
Because if I move the laser, the points move but the robot model remains stationary in the map?
Can I use hector_slam instead of amcl_diff.launch? If I can do, what I have to replace this file?
Please if you have at least one answer to all these questions, you give me a big help! Thank you! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230077/2d-pose-estimation-in-navigation-with-amcl/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it normal that I have to give the 2d pose estimate in rviz and it is not automatically done by amcl?

When? At the very beginning, AMCL needs to initialize its filter. This is done with a initialPose message given by the user, e.g. with RVIZ. If you don't provide an initialization, if I remember correctly, the particle set is initialized at pose-zero, I mean, the origin of your map or odom frame (which should coincide/have-the-same-pose at the beginning).

> Because if I move the laser, the points move but the robot model remains stationary in the map?

This is  not a problem with the lasers, AMCL asks to TF "if the robot has moved" to "update the filter". If you don't provide a transform (usually from [base_frame to odom](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Transforms)) AMCL will not update anything.

As every *filter*, AMCL has two main steps, Prediction (called UpdateAction inside the AMCL code, i.e. the motion model) and Measure incorporation (UpdateSensor inside AMCL, one of the two sensor models, i.e. *Likelihood Field Model* or the *Beam Model*). The first one is done using TF, so your system needs to provide that motion estimate. Then, the *predicted* estimate (according to the motion model) will be corrected/improved using the sensor readings, i.e. the laser scan and the known map.

So, to answer to your question: *if the points move but the robot model remains stationary in the map* you have some problems with TF, or you are not providing a motion estimate :-)

bye!

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-29**:
Thank you!